# How can I create procedural textures in code and fill in individual pixels one by one?

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, game-engine

When I say procedural textures I mean create a texture in code and fill in individual pixels one by one. I was curious if I could do this in BGE because I am creating procedual terrain and need to generate textures along with it.
Cheers, Keegan.